# What is the .plist.lockfile introduced in Lion?

Tags: macos, finder, preferences

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are my plists in ~/Library/Preferences accompanied by a matching lockfile in Lion?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19696/why-are-my-plists-in-library-preferences-accompanied-by-a-matching-lockfile-in)

Since upgrading to Lion, I have noticed that Lion is placing lockfiles that correspond to the plist in `~/Library/Preferences`. For example, in this folder I have both `com.apple.finder.plist` and `com.apple.finder.plist.lockfile`.

Any idea what these files are there for? I know what lockfiles are in general, but I dont understand why they may have been introduced in Lion.